# AWS ECS won't start tasks: http request timed out enforced after 4999ms

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an ECS cluster (fargate), task, and service I have had setup in Terraform for at least a year. I haven't touched it for a long while. My normal deployment for updating the code is to push a new container to the registry and then stop all tasks on the cluster with a script. Today, my service did not run a new task in response to that task being stopped. It's desired count is fixed at so it should.

I have go  in an tried to manually run this and I'm seeing this error.

> Unable to run task
> Http request timed out enforced after 4999ms

[image]

When I try to do this, a new stopped task is added to my stopped tasks lists. When I look into that task the stopped reason is "Deployment restart" and two of them are now showing "Task provisioning failed." which I think might be tasks the service tried to start. But these tasks do not show a started timestamp. The ones I start in the console have a started timestamp.

My site is now down and I can't get it back up. Does anyone know of a way to debug this? Is AWS ECS experiencing problems right now? I checked the health monitors and I see no issues.

Answer (score 0):

This was an AWS outage affecting Fargate in us-east-1. It's fixed now.